# Creating a Hive table with an irregular date/time format column

Tags: datetime, hadoop, hive, hiveql, simpledateformat

I have to create a Hive table from a csv and two of the columns have a date/time field that are formatted like so: 11/28/2018 8:35:23 PM or 11/30/2018 5:02:17 AM, etc. For example:

```
responseid        process_start             process_end                status

26                11/28/2018 8:35:23 PM     11/30/2018 5:02:17 AM      complete
```

I know that I can create these fields as a string first and then do something like this:

```
insert into table newtable 
select process_start, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(process_start, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss')) from oldtable;
```

But I'm not quite sure how to deal with the `AM` and `PM`. I'm not quite sure I have the `insert into table` syntax quite right either. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**SimpleDateFormat**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class docs as a format reference. Correct format is

`'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a'`

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('11/28/2018 8:35:23 PM', 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a'))
```

Returns:

```
2018-11-28 20:35:23
```

[**Insert into table**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingdataintoHiveTablesfromqueries) like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE newtable 
select responseid, 
       from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(process_start, 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a')) process_start,
       from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(process_end, 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a')) process_end, 
       status
  from oldtable;
```